# PySpark session builder doesn't start

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a problem regarding PySpark in Jupyter notebook. I installed Java, and Spark added the path variables and didn't get an error. However, when I write builder it keeps running and doesn't start. I waited more than 30 minutes to start but it just kept running. Code like below:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Practise').getOrCreate()
```

Comment: does your computer have the required resources to start a session?

Comment: Could you solve?

Comment: Can you post logs? It normally says what it's waiting for.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Could have something to do with your environment variables according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73341939/sparksession-initialization-takes-forever)

Haven't figured it out completely myself though.

All my envs were somehow deleted, then I got PySpark working again yesterday. But today it's again not running. It seems to run `spark = SparkSession.builer.getOrCreat()` for an infinite amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

use following

spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Practise').master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

This will work