# SparkSession initialization takes forever

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

SparkSession initialization takes forever without success.
Here is my code:

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.sql("select 'spark' as hello")
df.show()
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the end? Usually master and appName are added: `spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("demo").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()`

Comment: As mentioned, what are your Spark default configurations? Look at the actual server log output, not a Jupyter notebook cell

Comment: Are you running it locally or on a cluster manager? Like yarn, os, etc.

Comment: hi, sorry for the late answer
@bzu i do not get any error in the end, it just keep running for hours without any success or error

Comment: Did you run each line separately and you can confirm it gets stuck at `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` ? Also, please provide more info about where you are running this.

Comment: thank you for your replies, but i solved the problem yesterday.
it seems that the whole problem is the system cant find the correct path in enviromental variables

Comment: @winson could you please explain how you fixed it? You can answer your own question to get points :) I'm having the same issue and can't figure it out